# std::bind function taking std::unique_ptr as argument

Tags: c++, binding, c++14, move, unique-ptr

Please help me with the binding issue I face...

I have a class member method:

```
std::unique_ptr<TopoDS_Shape> test( std::unique_ptr<TopoDS_Shape> Shape ) const
{
    std::unique_ptr<TopoDS_Shape> Result = std::make_unique<TopoDS_Shape>();
    return( std::move( Result ) );
}
```

I need to construct a `std::function` pointer out of this. In order to do that, I need to use `std::bind` to forward this pointer as `test(...)` is a class member method:

```
std::function<std::unique_ptr<TopoDS_Shape>(std::unique_ptr<TopoDS_Shape>)> tTestFunction;

tTestFunction = std::bind( &ComponentModelModifier::test, this, std::placeholders::_1 );
```

Then, the std::function pointer is used in my threadpool add method with this signature:

```
template<typename FUNCTION, typename... ARGUMENTS>
auto ThreadPool::add( FUNCTION&& Function, ARGUMENTS&&... Arguments ) -> std::future<typename std::result_of<FUNCTION(ARGUMENTS...)>::type>
```

The call:

```
std::unique_ptr<TopoDS_Shape> tShape = std::make_unique<TopoDS_Shape>();

ThreadPool tp;
std::future<std::unique_ptr<TopoDS_Shape>> ResultFuture = tp.add( tTestFunction, std::move( tShape ) );
```

But the build always fails:

```
error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::reference_wrapper<std::_Bind<std::function<std::unique_ptr<TopoDS_Shape>(std::unique_ptr<TopoDS_Shape>)>(std::unique_ptr<TopoDS_Shape>)> >()>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
```

I know the std::unique_ptr is not copy-constructible. That's why I tried to use std::move but nothing worked yet...

I would be glad for any help or a kick in the right direction. Thanks in advance! Martin

Comment: Is your function indeed accepting `std::unique_ptr<TopoDS_Shape> Shape` _by value_?

Comment: I say yes. The function should overtake the ownership of the unique pointer used as argument. I hope you ment the test()...

Comment: Is this your real code? Where did the `reference_wrapper` come from?

Comment: Yes, it is. I made a little tracking and it seems the `std::reference_wrapper` comes from `std::result_of` as used in `auto ThreadPool::add( FUNCTION&& Function, ARGUMENTS&&... Arguments ) -> std::future<typename std::result_of<FUNCTION(ARGUMENTS...)>::type>`

Comment: Can you show us an actual [mcve] rather than tiny snippets?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `add()` method of my threadpool does not successfully deduce the argument types and thus reports the error message shown above. I tried to be more specific in my function call - especially in `std::move` where I tried to specify the resulting type. Also I need to modify the `test()` method signature to use shared pointer instead (see argument type). See my code below:

```
std::unique_ptr<TopoDS_Shape> test( const std::shared_ptr<TopoDS_Shape> Shape ) const
{
    std::unique_ptr<TopoDS_Shape> Result = std::make_unique<TopoDS_Shape>();
    return( std::move( Result ) );
}

...

std::future<std::unique_ptr<TopoDS_Shape>> ResultFuture = tp.add( tTestFunction, std::move<std::shared_ptr<TopoDS_Shape>>( tShape ) );
```

Then I am able to compile the code... It is still unclear why `std::unique_ptr` cannot be used as `test()` method argument type but at least I have a working solution.
Maybe it has something to do with the usage of std::function which must have all the arguments copy-constructible which is not the case of `std::unique_ptr`. I do not know how to invoke move constructor in here instead of deleted copy one.
If someone has an idea, please post.